# c++, is that possible to have two unions with the same name in different header files

Tags: c++, include, unions

There are two header files in a system, I need to include these two header files in order to interact with the system, the two header files are `agentRegistrationUnion` and `counterCollectUnionContent.h`, these two header files contains nothing special but just two unions, but these two unions have the same name, the only difference is the contents of the unions, the unions look like this:

```
union SIGNAL
{
    struct s1     ss1;
    struct s2     ss2;
    ......
};
```

I'm not able to change these header files, when I included these header files, I got `error: redefinition of 'union SIGNAL'`, how can I have both unions in my code?

my header file:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>

#include "agentRegistrationUnion.h" //I only want to separate these two files
#include "counterCollectUnion.h"

using namespace std;

class InvalidSig;

struct args{
    InvalidSig* context;
    string mname;
    union SIGNAL *content;
};

class InvalidSig{

    public:
        InvalidSig();
        ~InvalidSig();
        void Send_inval_sig();
        void Kill_proc();
        bool InitAttacker(char *argv);
        void LocateVictims();
        itc_msg* AllocMsg(union SIGNAL *content);
        void PrintVictims(itc_mbox_id_t vic);
        void *sendmsg(void *mname);

        static void *sendmsg_helper(void *ar){
            string n = ((args*)ar)->mname;
            return ((args*)ar)->context->sendmsg(&n);
        };


        multimap<string,string> mboxes;
        union SIGNAL *content;

};
```

Comment: Why not put these two headers in different namespaces ?

Comment: @PaulR Okay, I'm new to c++, I'll dig how to do it, thanks.

Comment: @PaulR Would you please write the answer how to do it, in my header file, I only want to separate the includings, all other code should be shared.

Comment: It looks like @MatthewMoss has already taken care of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `agentRegistrationUnion.h`:

```
namespace Agent {  // or some appropriate name
    union SIGNAL { ... };
}
```

In `counterCollectUnion.h`:

```
namespace Counter {  // or some appropriate name
    union SIGNAL { ... };
}
```

During use, refer to the desired union by prefixing the namespace:

```
Agent::SIGNAL signal;
signal.ss1 = ...;
```

If you can't change those header files, then this should work:

```
namespace Agent {
#include "agentRegistrationUnion.h"
}

namespace Counter {
#include "counterCollectUnion.h"
}

Agent::SIGNAL agentSignal;
Counter::SIGNAL counterSignal;
```

Comment: The OP says they are not able to change those headers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm not able to change the two header files, guess I need to create name spaces in my header files which include those two header files.

Comment: Edited my answers... You should be able to wrap the `#include` directives with namespaces (but that may depend somewhat on the content of the headers).

Answer (score 1):

You can change the name of the union without modifying the header with the following little trick:

`#define SIGNAL CCUCSIGNAL`

`#include <counterCollectUnionContent.h>`

`#undef SIGNAL`

Then you can refer to the union in counterCollectUnionContent.h as CCUCSIGNAL, and the other one remains SIGNAL

Comment: Macros are a poor solution for this - namespaces make much more sense for C++.

Comment: I agree that namespaces are the preferred solution in C++...*but* if you can't edit the headers and wrapping the `#include` directives won't work, then this is an option.